# GWT debug in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up 'GWT configuration' in IntelliJ Idea using JBoss 5.1 as my server.

I add a new GWT configuration in the DevMode parameters I give this:

```
-noserver -startupUrl http://localhost:8080/ -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -war "C:\Users\user\Documents\IdeaProjects\project\ru.project.maven\frontend\target\frontend-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT" ru.project.frontend.Frontend
```

After launch the debug configuration I am getting this in the console:

```
Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL:  http://localhost:8080/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

But when I access the page using that URL I get only background of my page.
Also I get:

> Connection received from 127.0.0.1:52435

in log when trying to start the page.

Point is that in eclipse the same project debugs fine. DevMod parameters is mostly the same except this:

> -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}"

when I add this parameter in Idea it gives me error:

> A port must be an integer Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1

Does anybody know how to configure debug in Idea in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Add also -nosuperDevMode as this defaults to ON(superDevMode)

This param is not mentioned in [gwtproject](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) but you can try add any not correct param and try launch. Intellij IDEA will tell you all available params.